# On creating pdf using jsPDF new pdf pages are appending with old pages , after click in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, jspdf

On creating pdf using jsPDF new pdf pages are appending with old pages ,

after click in angularjs

This is the code:

```
pdf.addPage().setFontSize(24).setFontStyle('bold').setFont('helvetica').text(20, 20, "Accident Images");
                        pdf.setLineWidth(0.5).line(15, 24, 200, 24);
```

//loading images in pdf

```
 for(j = 0;j < images.length;j++){
              if(j<images.length/2){
                   pdf.addImage(images[j].base64 ,'JPEG', 20, (25+(j*42)), 60, 40);
                                   }
               else {
                   pdf.addImage(images[j].base64 ,'JPEG', 85, (25+((j-2)*42)), 60, 40);
                     }
      }
```